# C# combining two strings

Tags: c#, active-directory, activedirectorymembership

I am working on an app that will create users in AD.  What I need want to do to be flexible is to create the users in a user defined OU (via GUI).  So if a user enters OU=test users, OU=test, I would like to take that and concatenate it to the rest of my AD path.  Basically this out allow me to build a string like 
string ldappath = "OU=Domain test Users,OU=test,DC=jmlab,DC=net"

This is how the user input would work:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpvos.jpg

My question is two fold.  One is there a way to have the user input only Test USers instead of the full path?  And two how can I combine the variables?

```
public string myDomain = "DC=jmlab,DC=net";
public string ou;
public string ldapPath = ou + myDefaultOU;
```

Comment: Can you not just use string.format("OU=Domain {0},OU={1};DC=jmlab,DC=net", "test Users", "test"); taking the input and manipulating it to fix the string?

Comment: If the user inputs only "Test Users", how would you know that he means the "Test Users" OU that is inside "test" OU or say the "Development" OU?. There could exist an OU in AD with this DN: "OU=Test Users, OU=Development, .."